# I want to make a news slideshow of nodes

Tags: javascript, views

I see the module [Views jQFX Nivo Slider](http://drupal.org/project/views_jqfx_nivoslider) and it's mentionned that the [current slideshow](http://www.lunarclips.com/) is a demo of it.
I installed the module and really don't know how to make something like that with it..
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module is a Views jQFX addon that integrates the Nivo Slider plugin with views.
The Views jQFX module is a dependency.
@Anoop Joseph -- Go through modules README.txt, it explains step by step configuration